# If $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$, does that mean ${f(x)}^3$ is discontinuous at $0$?

Tags: limits, continuity

If $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$, does that mean ${f(x)}^3$ is discontinuous at $0$?

I know this holds true for the function $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$, since $\frac{1}{x^3}$ is discontinuous at $0$ as well, but I am unsure if there is an example where this is untrue.

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ maps (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then it's true.  (Alex S's answer shows that if the domain is different then it can be false).

This follows because $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous everywhere.  Thus, $f = \sqrt[3]{f^3}$ is continuous wherever $f^3$ is.

Comment: Nice answer - and a great reminder of how useful proof by contrapositive can be :-)

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be given in rectangular coordinates by $$f(x+iy)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\geq 0\\ -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i & x<0.\end{cases}$$ Then $f$ is clearly discontinuous, but $f^3(x)=1$ for all $x$, so it is continuous.